# SVG Progress bar dashed on a scale of 75 of the circle

Tags: css, svg, progress-bar

I am stucked on an issue since now 2 days. I'll try to be short on this but this is what the result should look like :

[image]

I currently have no idea of how to do that, I'll try to start with a hardcoded value, and then I'll try to match the circle percentage with the real value. (Don't mind the circle in the middle, I'll do it later)

Here is what I came from until now, it makes no sense, but this is the only way I found to make 75% of a circle:

```css
svg {
  margin: 15px;
}

.loader {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 6;
    stroke-dasharray: 258;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    fill: transparent;
}
.loader.grey {
    stroke: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<svg class="loader-svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 130 130">
  <circle
    class="loader grey"
    cx="65"
    cy="65"
    r="55"
  ></circle>
</svg>
```

EDIT : I need to have the exact 10 dashes also and I don't need to animate it

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your question is, but if you are asking how to color part of your circle in a different color, the easiest way to do this would be to make a copy of the circle, adjust the width, place it on top of the first circle and change the color for that one.

Comment: the animation is to illustrate, it's not needed ;) simply remove it .. and you can have 10 or 20 or any number of dashes by simply adjusting the values. I simply gave a generic answer

Comment: I'll have a look at yours, and try to edit it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
svg {
  margin: 15px;
}

.loader {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 6;
    stroke-dasharray: 262,350; /*75%*/
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    fill: transparent;
    animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
.loader.grey {
    stroke: #c1c1c1;
}

@keyframes change {
  from{stroke-dasharray: 0,350;} /*0%*/
  to{stroke-dasharray: 350,350;} /*100%*/
}
```

```html
<svg class="loader-svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 130 130">
  <circle
    class="loader grey"
    cx="65"
    cy="65"
    r="55"
  ></circle>
</svg>
```

For the dash simply add another circle on the top:

```css
svg {
  margin: 15px;
}

.loader {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 6;
    stroke-dasharray: 262,350; /*75%*/
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    fill: transparent;
    animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
.loader.grey {
    stroke: #c1c1c1;
}
.dash {
 stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 6;
    stroke-dasharray: 17; /*adjust this to control the dashes*/ 
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    fill: transparent;
}

@keyframes change {
  from{stroke-dasharray: 0,350;} /*0%*/
  to{stroke-dasharray: 350,350;} /*100%*/
}
```

```html
<svg class="loader-svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 130 130">
  <circle
    class="loader grey"
    cx="65"
    cy="65"
    r="55"
  ></circle>
  <circle
    class="dash"
    cx="65"
    cy="65"
    r="55"
  ></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: I found out my problem is not what I thought it was, but this is still a nice answer, and I will use it not for the dash but for the green level

I will have a background grey circle, on z-index 2 I will have my green level, and on z-index 3 the white paths that will act like if the grey circle was dashed.